# GregorianCalendar year setting incorrectly

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java, and I am trying to figure out an oddity with GregorianCalendar.  It seems that the year is being set incorrectly (sometimes.)

I have made the following test function, to illustrate the problem:

```
public static void testTime(Calendar c) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
         new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");       
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));

   System.out.println("---------------------------------");
   c.setTimeInMillis(0);
   Date d = c.getTime();
   System.out.println("Time 0: "  + sdf.format(d) + 
         " (" + d.getTime() + ")");

   c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
   d = c.getTime();
   System.out.println("Year 2000: "  + sdf.format(d) + 
         " (" + d.getTime() + ")");
   System.out.println("---------------------------------");
}
```

This function takes a Calendar object, and produces output that should look like the following:

```
---------------------------------
Time 0: 1970/01/01 00:00:00 (0)
Year 2000: 2000/01/01 00:00:00 (946684800000)
---------------------------------
```

I am calling the function 3 times, from main;  The code to call it looks like:

```
   Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
   testTime(c);

   c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
   testTime(c);

   c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Phoenix"));
   testTime(c);
```

And finally, here is the output:

```
---------------------------------
Time 0: 1970/01/01 00:00:00 (0)
Year 2000: 2001/01/01 00:00:00 (978307200000)
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
Time 0: 1970/01/01 00:00:00 (0)
Year 2000: 2000/01/01 00:00:00 (946684800000)
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
Time 0: 1970/01/01 00:00:00 (0)
Year 2000: 2001/01/01 00:00:00 (978307200000)
---------------------------------
```

As you can see, when I call the function using a GregorianCalendar obtained from getInstance(), or one that has had the time zone set to
"America/Phoenix" (my local time zone), **the year is output as 2001**.  When I set the time zone to GMT, the year is (correctly I believe) output to **2000**.

Can someone please explain to me what I am missing?  I would like to use the Calendar by just creating one, setting some fields using some variables I have, and generating a date.  However, I need to make sure that the Date I am getting back does accurately reflect what I am setting;  I was going somewhat crazy with my unit tests until I realized that I was getting dates back that simply didn't match the year I was entering, so I made the above code to test.

**Edit**:  To be clear, I am not concerned with a small offset due to a timezone.  That I can understand, and account for.  A time difference of +-24 hours due to time zone is one thing;  A time difference of a year (2001 instead of 2000) is quite another.

If it matters, this Java is running on a 64bit Linux machine;  The java -showversion command returns:

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.  I have searched the boards here, and the internet as much as I can, and can't find anything that comes close to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what is going on.

When I set the year, it does indeed set the year to 2000.  It then seems to update the rest of its internal fields, using the time zone it has.

This means that when I set the year to 2000, it sets that field, and computes the time (including the time zone).  The previous time was Jan 1 00:00:00 1970.  It updates the year to 2000, moves the time back 7 hours (my offset) which gives a time of Dec 31 17:00 MST.  The year should really roll back to 1999, but it leaves the year at 2000, since that is what I set it to.  The resulting date is therefore Dec 31 17:00 2000.

When I print the date out, I set the time zone of my SimpleDateFormat to GMT.  It therefore moves the time forward 7 hours, to Jan 1 2001 00:00:00.

That is really confusing, but repeated tests show that it is indeed doing it that way.  Strange, but true.  The lesson here (for me) is that I should set the time zone of the output object to match the timezone of the calendar. It will then show dates that match what I input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears when you try to reassign the new value with the new YEAR to the Date object.
This code:

```
c.setTimeInMillis(0);
       Date d = c.getTime();
       System.out.println("Time 0: "  + sdf.format(d) + 
             " (" + d.getTime() + ")");
```

does not work. But this one:

```
c.setTimeInMillis(0);
       System.out.println("Time 0: "  + sdf.format(c.getTime()) + 
             " (" + c.getTime() + ")");
```

works for me for the "no timezone" case.

For the America/Phoenix case, this line was the problem:

```
c.setTimeInMillis(0);
```

but you can replace it with

```
c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(0);
```

and it will work.

Comment: The thing is, I get the correct year (2000) when I specify GMT+0 (or GMT+0000), but incorrect when I specify none or America/Phoenix.  According to the docs on TimeZone, it is valid to specify GMT+0 as a timezone, so I don't think that's the issue, and the getDefaultInstance() for calendar is supposed to construct it with the default Timezone, not none.  Thanks for the reply, but I will have to keep digging I think to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, I misread this. You're right GMT+0 gives the correct result. I will edit my answer.